# How do I hook a new Mac Book Pro Retina up to dual DisplayPort monitors?

Tags: display, macbook-pro, displayport

I have two DisplayPort monitors.  These are regular DisplayPort monitors, not mini-Display Port, not made by Apple and not made specifically for Mac.

I would like to buy a new Mac Book Pro Retina.  How can I hook it up to my dual DisplayPorts? What type of adapters do I need?

And, if I can't do that, how can I hook it up to a single DisplayPOrt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From EveryMac…

> This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 2560x1600 on two external displays via Thunderbolt. Alternately, it can support a single display up to 2560x1600 via Thunderbolt and a single 1080p display at up to 60 Hz, 3840x2160 at 30 Hz, or 4096x2160 at 24 Hz via HDMI.

If you have 2 Thunderbolt ports, you can use 2 miniDP to Display Port cables, one from each port, just as though the ports were miniDP as they are backwardly-compatible.

See [Thunderbolt ports and displays: Frequently asked questions (FAQ)](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/ht5219)